# Combine several columns in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this.

[image]

I want to combine several columns like this.

[image]

I don't know how to solve this.
How can I duplicate 'date' columns? and How can I append like that.
Hope for help. Thank you.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I only used pd.DataFrame(). I just want to make it like the second data frame.

Comment: what's the logic to deriving your second dataframe?

Comment: sorry. it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry about that. I'll have another go.
The solution is fairly straight forward.
There is a much more efficient way of achieving this but I'll leave that to you.

```py
data = [ [ 20210101, 1,4,7 ],[ 20210102, 2,5,8 ],[ 20210103, 3,6,9 ] ]

new = []

for a,b,c,d in data:
    new.append( [a, b] )

for a,b,c,d in data:
    new.append( [a, c] )

for a,b,c,d in data:
    new.append( [a, d] )

for a in new:
    print( a )
```

Comment: Could you add some formatting? Indent your code by 4 spaces, so it's much easier to read. :) Also, an explanation is always helpful; it would be nice to have one :)